# Exponential function to distribute rewards to an unknown amount of players, with fixed min and max

Tags: calculus, functions, exponential-function

*this is my first question on Math SE, let me know in comments if I should update some things!*

I'm creating a reward curve for a video game. Here are the rules:

- The top player is rewarded 100 times more than the bottom player (assume 100pts and 1pt as rewards).
- Any player ranked N receives strictly more than the player ranked N+1
- The difference in reward between players [N, N+1] is higher than the difference in reward between players [N+1, N+2] (non linear)
- The number of players is unknown (from 100 to 1m for instance)

So I am trying to define F following function :

- F(1, n) = 100
- F(n, n) = 1
- F(x, n) = ???
- F is following something looking like an exponential law?

Would someone please help me figure it out ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `f(x,n) = 100^((n-x)/(n-1))` would be one way to do it

Comment: Yep exactly, thanks !